# Creating buckets with Google Cloud Storage + Node.js

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage

I want to be able to dynamically create buckets in Google Cloud Storage. I am using the MEAN.io stack, so I want to do this in Node.js on my backend. 
I'm having trouble finding apis to help me, is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

UPDATE: Here I've tried using the Google-Node.js api, but nothing is happening. I tried to then authenticate it in case that's the problem, but I'm not really sure where to go from here.

```
googleAuth.authenticate(
    credentials.jwt,
    function(err, token) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        console.log(token);

        googleapis
            .discover('storage', 'v1')
            .execute(function(err, client) {
                if (err) console.log(err);

                client.storage.buckets.insert({'project': credentials.project}, {'name': bucketname}).execute();
            })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Cloud Storage JSON API](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/) is probably the API you want to use. You can code against it directly, or you could use a library like the [Google APIs Node.js Client](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/).

Comment: I tried using the Google APIs Node.js Client, and no error is being logged, but also nothing is happening. I'm updating my question to show the code I'm trying -- why wouldn't this do anything?